# CopyFromRecordset to Excel copies numbers only

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy whole recordset to the Excel worksheet but it copies properly numbers only. Cells where should be text are blank. Is someone able to help me?

Here is my code:

```
public cn As New ADODB.Connection
public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
public rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
public strFile$, strCon$, strsQL$

Sub macro() 
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cn.Open
    strsQL = "SELECT A, B, C FROM SqlTable5"
    rs.Open strsQL, cn

    Set rs2 = rs.Clone
    For iCols = 0 To rs2.Fields.Count - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs2.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
    rs.Close
    rs2.Close
    cn.Close
    Close Connection
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

SqlTable5 is set in Name Manager.

Comment: Perhaps, the empty text in the source?

Comment: But SqlTable5 is defined range and I can see data in those cells. I don't think SELECT could return only numbers. Couldn't it?

Comment: Could you put sample workbook to some cloud storage for further investigation (with sensitive data removed)?

Comment: It seems that that the issue is caused by mixing formats in area of one column - some records were formatted as text and some as numbers. When I set text format for whole column it is properly copied by copyfromrecordset. However, thank you for your help because I have noticed it while preparing workbook for you to investigate :)

Comment: Ha-ha :) Glad that "helped"! 